# UITextView textViewShouldBeginEditing crashes when tapped more than once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

I have a UIViewController. In this controller I programmatically create a UITextView and set its delegate as my controller. I do this because I dont want to start editing the textView when I tap it.

**ViewDidLoad method**

```
UITextView* textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 10, 302, 200)];
[textView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
[textView release];
```

I implemented the textViewShouldBeginEditing method to return NO here to disable the keyboard from showing up.

**textViewShouldBeginEditing method**

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"Shouldbegin");
    return NO;
}
```

**The problem that appears**

When I tap the textView it works once, but if i tap it again it will crash the application without any log. The weird thing when I hold the textView and release it, it will work like I want it to work. A normal single tap on the other hand doesn't work a second time.

**Edit**

Single tapping quickly after each other also seems to work, so it seems that it wont work after i wait x seconds.

After some testing I found out it seems to be an iOS 5.X > bug. When running my App in a 4.3 device/simulator it works like it should. The error log on a iOS 5.1 device says the following:

```
Date/Time:       2012-04-17 14:00:49.497 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000014
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   TextInput                       0x36bf69e8 TI::Favonius::BeamSearch::choose_hit_test_node(WTF::RefPtr<TI::Favonius::SearchNode> const&, WTF::RefPtr<TI::Favonius::KeyAreaNode> const&, WTF::RefPtr<TI::Favonius::SearchNode> const&, WTF::RefPtr<TI::Favonius::SearchNode> const&) + 12
1   TextInput                       0x36bf6d1e TI::Favonius::BeamSearch::update_for_touch(unsigned int, WTF::PassRefPtr<TI::Favonius::KeyAreaNode>) + 602
2   TextInput                       0x36bfb5c2 TI::Favonius::StrokeBuildManager::update_search_for_touch(unsigned int, int) + 66
3   TextInput                       0x36bfb97c TI::Favonius::StrokeBuildManager::key_down_or_drag_hit_test_for_UI(bool, CGPoint, double, int, int, float, bool, ZT::LayoutDictionaryContext&, bool, int) + 216
4   TextInput                       0x36bddf54 TIInputManagerZephyr::simulate_touches_for_input_string() + 344
5   TextInput                       0x36bed8ba -[TIKeyboardInputManagerZephyr candidates] + 214
6   UIKit                           0x31066616 -[UIKeyboardImpl generateAutocorrectionReplacements:] + 82
7   UIKit                           0x31108a96 __71-[UITextInteractionAssistant scheduleReplacementsForRange:withOptions:]_block_invoke_0 + 370
8   UIKit                           0x3110ec62 -[UITextSelectionView calculateAndShowReplacements:] + 6
9   Foundation                      0x3762192c __NSFireDelayedPerform + 408
10  CoreFoundation                  0x361a1a2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
11  CoreFoundation                  0x361a1692 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 358
12  CoreFoundation                  0x361a0268 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3612349e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
14  CoreFoundation                  0x36123366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
15  GraphicsServices                0x324e3432 GSEventRunModal + 130
16  UIKit                           0x30e70e76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
```

Comment: remove [textView release]; from your ViewDidLoad method and then try it.

Comment: On my side its working fine.But i'm using ARC Enable.

Comment: Well i have ARC disabled. The controller where the textview is presented is pushed onto a navigationstack and there is some other code around it, but it should work if you ask me too... weirdly enough it does only for a small part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found out it seems to be an iOS 5.X > bug. When running my App in a 4.3 device/simulator it works like it should.

Look in my main post where i edited the logfile.

Comment: If you are not using ARC, then you should create a property (retain, nonatomic) for the textView so that it is not released after the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 1):

I did find a solution.  I don't really like working around Apple bugs but sometimes you have to.  It is three steps...

1) replace the default keyboard with an invisible view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myTextView.inputView = customKeyboard;
}
```

2) answer YES to allow editing

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    return YES;
}
```

3) In textViewDidChangeSelection resign the first responder to hide the cursor

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Seems like an OK work around :-). I dont remember what I did to fix it eventually.

Comment: I cannot change the keyboard type because it has to be the numpad, and the remaining steps are not working for me .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to start editing of UITextView when you tapped it:

```
UITextView* textView = ...;
textView.editable = NO;
```

Comment: I also want to know if it is getting clicked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

   [txtView resignFirstResponder];

}
```

and release txtView in dealloc method

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**
**The best and easy way to solve this just make undo manager as false**

```
textView.undoManager?.disableUndoRegistration()
```

This error appears if you have change the view at run time like within the table, and cell will be reloaded on tapping,